# print out encrypted image (array of bytes) into new Image

Tags: java, image, swing, buffer

What I'm doing wrong I want the encrypted bytes of the image to create a new image 
but it throw exception IllegalArgumentException:

```
RC6Algorithm rc6 = new RC6Algorithm();
byte[] enc = rc6.encrypt(imageByte, key.getBytes());
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(enc);
BufferedImage   newImage = ImageIO.read(in);
ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", new File(
                    "d:/s.jpg"));

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
image == null!
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly enough, the encrypted bytes of an image file, cannot be decoded as an image file.

You could try to encrypt the bytes of the image's uncompressed pixels instead, then have these bytes represent the pixel of another image, and save this image if you want. If you want to be able to decrypt the resulting image back to the original unencrypted image though, you'll need to write the encrypted image in a lossless format such as PNG. JPEG won't do.

Comment: Sorry no, too much to leave to personal preferences. Start by showing your personal attempt at doing what I proposed